# How to customize Application Web Part paging?

Tags: branding, template, paging

Good Day!
I often paste Application Web Part to Wiki Page. I select some List view for this Web Part. The view shows the List elements by blocks of the specified size. It gets the paging with black arrow images “next.gif” and “prev.gif” (src=” /_layouts/15/1049/images/next.gif”). 
I need to replace them by my button pictures “Next” and “Previous” in Site Assets Library. To do this I paste JS code to my page.
But I create many pages with web parts and I need to paste the JS code every time. I would like to replace the default paging images in page rendering to give web parts with my custom paging buttons.

Someone, please, tell me where I can find the template for branding the paging buttons. I would like to use my button images for Apps web part.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Good day,The question is still actual. 
I use js to override the paging buttons on every page with the "Favourite Cars" List (or another list).

1. I paste to my page the Web Part with "Favourite Cars" list
2. Then I paste "Media and Content" -> "Script Editor" to this page and add JS. It changes my icons.
I am searching for the more effective way.

How can I paste the Apps Web Part to my page with my custom icons? Without Script Editor pasting on every page